# Do you use attach() or call variables by name or slicing?

Tags: r, coding-style

Many intro R books and guides start off with the practice of attaching a `data.frame` so that you can call the variables by name. I have always found it favorable to call variables with `$` notation or square bracket slicing `[,2]`. That way I can use multiple `data.frame`s without confusing them and/or use iteration to successively call columns of interest. I noticed Google recently posted [coding guidelines for R](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-r-style.html) which included the line

> 1) attach: avoid using it

How do people feel about this practice?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I never use attach. `with` and `within` are your friends.

Example code:

```
> N <- 3
> df <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(N),x2=runif(N))
> df$y <- with(df,{
   x1+x2
 })
> df
          x1         x2          y
1 -0.8943125 0.24298534 -0.6513271
2 -0.9384312 0.01460008 -0.9238312
3 -0.7159518 0.34618060 -0.3697712
> 
> df <- within(df,{
   x1.sq <- x1^2
   x2.sq <- x2^2
   y <- x1.sq+x2.sq
   x1 <- x2 <- NULL
 })
> df
          y        x2.sq     x1.sq
1 0.8588367 0.0590418774 0.7997948
2 0.8808663 0.0002131623 0.8806532
3 0.6324280 0.1198410071 0.5125870
```

Edit: hadley mentions transform in the comments. here is some code:

```
 > transform(df, xtot=x1.sq+x2.sq, y=NULL)
       x2.sq       x1.sq       xtot
1 0.41557079 0.021393571 0.43696436
2 0.57716487 0.266325959 0.84349083
3 0.04935442 0.004226069 0.05358049
```

Comment: `transform` is another useful variation on within.

Comment: Actually I just noticed that unlike `attach()`, `with()` doesn't "resolve through" functions.  First set up `printx <- function { print(x) }`. Now, `with(list(x=42), printx())` fails even though `with(list(x=42), print(x))` and `attach(list(x=42)); printx()` succeed!  :(

Answer (score 13):

I much prefer to use `with` to obtain the equivalent of `attach` on a single command:

```
 with(someDataFrame,  someFunction(...))
```

This also leads naturally to a form where `subset` is the first argument:

```
 with(subset(someDataFrame,  someVar > someValue),
      someFunction(...))
```

which makes it pretty clear that we operate on a selection of the data.  And while many modelling function have both `data` and `subset` arguments, the use above is more consistent as it also applies to those functions who do not have  `data` and `subset` arguments.

Answer (score 8):

The main problem with attach is that it can result in unwanted behaviour. Suppose you have an object with name xyz in your workspace. Now you attach dataframe abc which has a column named xyz. If your code reference to xyz, can you guarantee that is references to the object or the dataframe column? If you don't use attach then it is easy. just xyz refers to the object. abc$xyz refers to the column of the dataframe.

One of the main reasons that attach is used frequently in textbooks is that it shortens the code.

Comment: I have noticed that some textbooks say "don't do this, attach is being used to simplify the examples".

Answer (score 7):

"Attach" is an evil temptation. The *only place where it works well is in the classroom setting* where one is given a single dataframe and expected to write lines of code to do the analysis on that one dataframe. The user is unlikely to ever use that data again once the assignement is done and handed in.

However, *in the real world*, more data frames can be added to the collection of data in a particular project. Furthermore one often copies and pastes blocks of code to be used for something similar. Often one is borrowing from something one did a few months ago and cannot remember the nuances of what was being called from where. In these circumstances one gets drowned by the previous use of "attach."

Answer (score 3):

I prefer not to use `attach()`, as it is far too easy to run a batch of code several times each time calling `attach()`. The data frame is added to the search path each time, extending it unnecessarily. Of course, good programming practice is to also `detach()` at the end of the block of code, but that is often forgotten.

Instead, I use xxx$y or xxx[,"y"]. It's more transparent.

Another possibility is to use the data argument available in many functions which allows individual variables to be referenced within the data frame. e.g., `lm(z ~ y, data=xxx)`.

Comment: Sometimes I am calling from various data frames and global variables, and this system means never having an incorrect calculation performed.

Answer (score 3):

Just like Leoni said, `with` and `within` are perfect substitutes for `attach`, but I wouldn't completely dismiss it. I use it sometimes, when I'm working directly at the R prompt and want to test some commands before writing them on a script. Especially when testing multiple commands, `attach` can be a more interesting, convenient and even harmless alternative to `with` and `within`, since after you run `attach`, the command prompt is clear for you to write inputs and see outputs.

Just make sure to `detach` your data after you're done!

Answer (score 2):

While I, too, prefer not to use `attach()`, it does have its place when you need to persist an object (in this case, a `data.frame`) through the life of your program when you have several functions using it.  Instead of passing the object into every R function that uses it, I think it is more convenient to keep it in one place and call its elements as needed.

That said, I would only use it if I know how much memory I have available and only if I make sure that I `detach()` this `data.frame` once it is out of scope.

Am I making sense?