# Which is the best method to apply a script repetitively to n .csv files in R?

Tags: r, loops, xts

**My situation**:

1. I have a number of csv files all with the same suffix pre .csv, but the first two characters of the file name are different (ie AA01.csv, AB01.csv, AC01.csv etc)
2. I have an R script which I would like to run on each file. This file essentially extracts the data from the .csv and assigns them to vectors / converts them into timeseries objects. (For example, AA01 xts timeseries object, AB01 xts object)

**What I would like to achieve**:

1. Embed the script within a larger loop (or as appropriate) to sequentially run over each file and apply the script
2. Remove the intermediate objects created (see code snippet below)
3. Leave me with the final xts objects created from each raw data file (ie AA01 to AC01 etc as Values / Vectors etc)

What would be the right way to embed this script in R? Sorry, but I am a programming noob!

My script code below...heading of each column in each CSV is DATE, TIME, VALUE

```
    # Pull in Data from the FileSystem and attach it
AA01raw<-read.csv("AA01.csv")
attach(AA01raw)
#format the data for timeseries work
cdt<-as.character(Date)
ctm<-as.character(Time)
tfrm<-timeDate(paste(cdt,ctm),format ="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
val<-as.matrix(Value)
aa01tsobj<-timeSeries(val,tfrm)
#convert the timeSeries object to an xts Object
aa01xtsobj<-as.xts(tsobj)
#remove all the intermediate objects to leave the final xts object
rm(cdt)
rm(ctm)
rm(aa01tsobj)
rm(tfrm)
gc()
```

and then repeat on each .csv file til all xts objects are extracted.

ie, what we would end up within R, ready for further applications are:

```
aa01xtsobj, ab01xtsobj, ac01xtsobj....etc
```

any help on how to do this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: what package is `timeSeries` in? You should include this information in the question. Ideally include minimal, reproducible code.

Comment: timeSeries is in the package of the same name. apologies.

Comment: `attach()` is dangerous! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310247/do-you-use-attach-or-call-variables-by-name-or-slicing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I find a for loop and lists is well enough for stuff like this. Once you have a working set of code it's easy enough to move from a loop into a function which can be `sapply`ied or similar, but that kind of vectorization is idiosyncratic anyway and probably not useful outside of private one-liners.

You probably want to avoid assigning to multiple objects with different names in the workspace (this a FAQ which usually comes up as "how do I assign() . . .").

Please beware my untested code.

A vector of file names, and a list with a named element for each file.

```
files <- c("AA01.csv", "AA02.csv")
lst <- vector("list", length(files))
names(lst) <- files
```

Loop over each file.

```
library(timeSeries)

for (i in 1:length(files)) {
    ## read strings as character
    tmp <- read.csv(files[i], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    ## convert to 'timeDate'
    tmp$tfrm <- timeDate(paste(tmp$cdt, tmp$ctm),format ="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"))
    ## create timeSeries object
    obj <- timeSeries(as.matrix(tmp$Value), tmp$tfrm)
    ## store object in the list, by name
    lst[[files[i]]] <- as.xts(obj)
}

## clean up
rm(tmp, files, obj)
```

Now all the read objects are in `lst`, but you'll want to test that the file is available, that it was read correctly, and you may want to modify the names to be more sensible than just the file name.

Print out the first object by name index from the list:

```
lst[[files[1]]]
```

Comment: When appropriately edited, i get this error: 'Error: object 'tfrm' not found Error in timeSeries(as.matrix(tmp$VALUE), tfrm) : error in evaluating the argument 'charvec' in selecting a method for function 'timeSeries''.// tfrm in the original snippet was meant to house the appropriately converted timeSeries index. ie, cdt was the Date in column 1, ctm was the Time in column 2 and both needed to be pasted together as characters per the requirement for timeSeries to work.

Comment: ie tfrm doesn't exist in the original CSV; just DATE, TIME, VALUE are the columns in the original CSV. tfrm is the correctly formatted combination of DATE & TIME.

Comment: even converting: obj <- timeSeries(as.matrix(tmp$Value), tfrm) to obj <- timeSeries(as.matrix(tmp$Value), tmp$tfrm) then gives the error// Error in xts(as.matrix(x@.Data), order.by = order.by, ...) : 
  NROW(x) must match length(order.by)

Comment: I changed it to timeSeries(as.matrix(tmp$Value), tmp$tfrm)
this should help show you need for minimal, reproducible code (mine is still untested except by you)

Comment: ok, brilliant - thank you! this now seems to create the lst. but lst seems to be just one giant list...is there a way of extracting aa01 vs aa02? they don't seem to be individually extracted.

Comment: i can do this manually (ie: aa01<-lst[files[[1]]], aa02<=lst[[files[[2]]], but ideally want to incorporate that in the code! thank you so much for your help; i really appreciate it and you're very kind to lend your expertise.

Comment: it's just not a good idea to do so, but if you really must for (i in 1:length(lst)) assign(names(lst)[i], lst[i])

Answer (score 25):

Be sure to use Rs `dir` command to produce the list of filenames instead of manually entering them in.

```
filenames = dir(pattern="*01.csv")
for( i in 1:length(filenames) )
{
  ...
```

Comment: If you have a list of file names, you can just `lapply`, something along the lines of `lapply(list.of.files, my.function, argument1, argument2...)`.