# R looping file import

Tags: r, loops, import

Is there a way to loop this?

```
jan2018 <- read.csv(file = 'Jan2018.csv')
feb2018 <- read.csv(file = 'Feb2018.csv')
mar2018 <- read.csv(file = 'Mar2018.csv')
apr2018 <- read.csv(file = 'Apr2018.csv')
may2018 <- read.csv(file = 'May2018.csv')
jun2018 <- read.csv(file = 'Jun2018.csv')
jul2018 <- read.csv(file = 'Jul2018.csv')
aug2018 <- read.csv(file = 'Aug2018.csv')
sep2018 <- read.csv(file = 'Sep2018.csv')
```

How would the code look like?

**ANSWER:**

Here is a good example of how you would automatically import multiple files at once:

```
list_of_files <- list.files(pattern = "^starting_text")

data <- list_of_files %>%
  setNames(nm = c("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul")) %>%
  map_df(read_xlsx, .id = "month")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is the best method to apply a script repetitively to n .csv files in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799096/which-is-the-best-method-to-apply-a-script-repetitively-to-n-csv-files-in-r)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import multiple .csv files at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-at-once)

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
file_names <- list.files(pattern = ".*2018.csv")
dates <- tolower(sub(".csv", "", file_names))

myList <- lapply(file_names, read.csv)


for (i in 1:length(myList)) {

  assign(paste0(dates[i]), as.data.frame(myList[[i]]))

}
```

Comment: `list_of_files <- list.files(pattern = "^starting_text")

data <- list_of_files %>%

  setNames(nm = c("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul")) %>%

  map_df(read_xlsx, .id = "month")`