# R Loop to copy files into different folders according to values in data frame

Tags: r, loops, image-processing

I want to write a simple loop that will create copies of all of the images in a folder (.jpg) and sort them into different folders according to the values in a table.

For example if I had three images and wanted to move them into folders according to this table:
[image]

I can read in the files using

```
files <- list.files(dir, pattern="*.JPG", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)
```

but I could use some help coding the loop that will use a conditional statement to create copies of the files in new folders using the appropriate string from the 'destination' column, which corresponds to the factor 'group'.

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958516/looping-through-all-files-in-directory-in-r-applying-multiple-commands) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799096/which-is-the-best-method-to-apply-a-script-repetitively-to-n-csv-files-in-r) but different in that I want to copy images and rename them based on the values in the table rather than cycle through multiple tables.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: See `?file.copy`. Build the full or relative paths to your destinations and `file.copy(from = data$name, to = data$destination)`. No loop needed. Not sure what conditional statement you think is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @Gregor Thomas, this is what I came up with:

```
dir <- "C:/path"

setwd(dir)
data <- read.csv("key.csv")

subfolder_names <- data$destination
for (j in 1:length(subfolder_names)){
  folder<-dir.create(paste0(dir,subfolder_names[j]))
}

files <- list.files(dir, pattern="*.JPG", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)

file.copy(from = file.path(files), to = file.path(data$destination, data$name))
```