# The attached object won't change when I modify it?

Tags: r

Code to reproduce the problem:

Creates a data frame with one column "a".

```
dataObj=data.frame(a=1) 
> dataObj
  a
1 1
```

Attach dataObj

```
attach(dataObj) 
> a
[1] 1
```

Modify dataObj, but the value of a is still unchanged.

```
dataObj[1,"a"]=3
> a
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?attach`:

```
The database is not actually attached. Rather, a new environment is created on
the search path and the elements of a list (including columns of a data frame)
or objects in a save file or an environment are copied into the new environment.
```

A copy is added to the search path, not the object itself.  When you modify the original, the copy is unchanged.

It is advised (by many) to avoid `attach`.  `with` is a handy substitute.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310247/in-r-do-you-use-attach-or-call-variables-by-name-or-slicing