# R: Are there any known issues when plyr/dplyr/data.table and plm packages used together

Tags: r, plyr, plm

I have been forming a panel dataset based on many other panel datasets. I have been puzzled by `data.table` or even base R function `merge()` that often alter the ordering of rows. So after much trial and error I used the following from `plyr`:

```
join(x, y, by=c("Firm", "Index"))
```

Finally, when I prepared by final panel dataset and used the `attach()` function and `plm` package for the analysis, I get the following error:

> Error in pdim.default(index[[1]], index[[2]]) 
>   when I investigate further using

```
options(error=recover)
```

I find

```
stop(cat("duplicate couples (time-id)\n"))
```

Kindly suggest what could be wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: try `sort = FALSE` inside `merge()`.

Comment: @Gregor why don't attach()?

Comment: It can cause problems that are difficult to debug when attached columns get out of sync with each other (and with the data frame). `with()` is a good alternative for single commands that don't have a data argument. But many commands (like `plm`!) have a `data` argument so that you don't need to `attach` or use `with` at all.

Comment: See the [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1310247/903061) for more details on the badness of `attach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like in your data (maybe due to the merging process) you have individuals which have the same value in the time index more than once (or more than one NA).
You could either look at your data or try `table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")` to find out which.

Comment: Yes I intentionally have repeating values in Index. The provided code gives:  1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28 
   1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1  . What does it mean?